# How do I tell NVCC to generate an x64 obj?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am having trouble compiling as x64 using VS 2006 CUDA 4.0 x64. The NVCC compiler generates a 32-bit obj file, then the MS linker complains that the obj file is not targeted for x64. Is there any way to tell NVCC to generate a x64 obj?

Comment: no, you have to download the 64-bit toolkit.

Comment: I do have the 64 bit took kit

Comment: Try passing `-m 64` as additional command-line parameter to NVCC

Answer (score 2):

`nvcc` can be explicitly forced to emit 64 bit host object files by passing the `--machine 64` or `-m64` [option](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior). Similarly, it can be forced to emit 32 bit host object files by passing the `--machine 32` or `-m32`

[This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered question queue for the CUDA tag]